# Change statusbar font color

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, angular-nativescript

Is still possible to change statusbar color on certain page by using angular2/nativescript?

I tried to use this way from docs but it doesn't work.

```
import { topmost } from "tns-core-modules/ui/frame";

if (topmost().ios) {
   var navigationBar = topmost().ios.controller.navigationBar;
   // 0: default
   // 1: light
   navigationBar.barStyle = 1;
}
```

Playground example is here: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=z8CnAz

PS: I need to have black status bar on first page and white on second one. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` key to `true` in your `info.plist`

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: It's still black.

Answer (score 0):

You could set load event to `ActionBar` with next handler:

```ts
export function onActionBarLoaded(args: EventData) {
    const actionBar = <ActionBar>args.object;

    if (actionBar.ios) {
        var navigationBar = actionBar.page.frame.ios.controller.navigationBar;
        navigationBar.barStyle = 1;
    }
}
```

[Test playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=b9zJLA).

Comment: but what to do if I want to have actionbar hidden?

Comment: In iOS if you hide ActionBar then StatusBar lose it background. Have you read [NativeScript 5.0 iOS Safe Area Support](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-5-ios-safe-area-support)?